# How to store and retrieve XML data from DB2 using WSO2 DSS

Tags: xml, db2, wso2-data-services-server

How do I properly store and access XML data in a database (IBM DB2) using WSO2 DSS?

We have a table similar to the following with two columns:

- id INTEGER
- xmlData XML

The `xmlData` column contains the actual XML document I wish to store.

I've managed to get the following insert operation to work:

```
<query id="insert_product" useConfig="DB2">
    <sql>INSERT INTO product (XmlData) VALUES (:XmlData)</sql>
    <param name="XmlData" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```

The insert works fine, but the actual data needs to be wrapped in a pesky CDATA section:

```
<xmlData>
    <![CDATA[
        <product>
            <code>acp</code>
            <name>A cool product</name>
        </product>
    ]]>
</xmlData>
```

I'm querying the table using the following query:

```
<query id="get_product" useConfig="DB2">
    <sql>SELECT id, xmlData FROM product WHERE id = :id</sql>
    <result element="product">
        <element column="id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="xmlData" name="xmlData" xsdType="string"/>
    </result>
    <param name="id" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
</query>
```

The query works fine, except that the output for the XML column is escaped:

```
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <xmlData>
        &lt;product&gt;
            &lt;code&gt;acp&lt;/code&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;A cool product&lt;/name&gt;
        &lt;/product&gt;
    </xmlData>
</product>
```

This is to be expected, I guess, since the DSS data type for the column is `string`.

The data is stored in the database as XML (DB2 validates it for well-formedness).

**The question:**
How do I tell DSS to handle the column data as XML? No CDATA section should be necessary in the insert and output must not be escaped.

**Dislaimer:**
Needless to say, the above is a simplified example. The actual XML that gets stored in the table is a long, complex document, that needs to be understood only partially.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to accept &lt; values?

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest way is to convert the *xmlData* into **XMLTABLE**.

More information at developerworks: [Retrieving XML data in relational format](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0708nicola/).

Then you can convert it to a complex element result: [Grouping Data into Complex Elements](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS310/Grouping+Data+into+Complex+Elements)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, which was about using WSO2 DSS to retrieve XML data stored in a database. You're just presenting another solution to the actual storage (and retrieval) of the data. Using this approach, one runs into exactly the same issue, which I present in my question.

Comment: @Kallja of course it doesn't answer your question completely, because AFAIK WSO2 DSS does not have an output mapping for XML data types. This is a workaround to it. In the past I've searched for an answer and this was the best solution I found for a problem just like yours. Using this approach you'll not run into the same issue since your data will be presented as mapped data types like string and integer. Please, give it a try.